# How do I scrape only the numbers and not the text following the numbers?

Tags: python, html, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

Following is extract from the HTML code I would like to web scrape from. Given:

```
<tbody>
  <tr>
     <th>SAT Math</th>
     <td>"541 average"</td>
  </tr>
</tbody>
```

I am using Python and Beautiful Soup to web scrape and extract out the 541 but my problem is:

1. Once I do extract the "541 average" how to get rid of all the excess material - for example for the GPA how do I get rid of the "average"?

Thank you so much, I would be extremely grateful to anyone who can help!

(Sorry I am a beginner to Python and web scraping)

Current code:

```
import urllib2
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

import csv
from datetime import datetime

quote_page = 'https://www.collegedata.com/cs/data/college/college_pg02_tmpl.jhtml?schoolId='+str(i)
page = urllib2.urlopen(quote_page)

soup = BeautifulSoup(page, 'html.parser')
table = soup.find("div", attrs={"id":"section8"})

name_box = soup.find('div', attrs={'class': 'cp_left'}).find('h1')
name = name_box.text.strip() # strip() is used to remove starting and trailing
print name

datasets = []
for row in table.find_all("tr")[1:]:

    if ((zip(th.get_text() for th in row.find_all("th")))!=[(u'SAT Math',)]):
        continue

    dataset = zip((th.get_text() for th in row.find_all("th")), (td.get_text() for td in row.find_all("td")))
    datasets.append(dataset)

    for dataset in datasets:
        for field in dataset:
            print format(field[1])
```

Comment: can you show your existing soup statements?

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please take the time to read [ask] and the links it contains. [Beautiful Soup Documentation](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#beautiful-soup-documentation)

Comment: Hi @PaulaLivingstone I've added my existing soup statements to my original post. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you'll always have " average" text in the result you can try to extract only the number with the use of regular expression.

You basically need to manipulate the string.

Something like this:

```
import re

s = "541 average"
extractTheNumber = re.findall('(\d+?)\s', s)

print(extractTheNumber[0])
```

Which will match as many consecutive number characters till a space is found (the space is excluded from the the match.)

Try your regex on this tool, which might be very useful: https://regex101.com/

Comment: Hi, I know this answer is from 4 years ago, but I was curious on knowing why the numbers have a [] around them...